# Random players from both teams SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, random

[table from where teamID and PlayerId fetching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxstO.png)

I have 2 teams in my database,
and a table with PlayerID along with  TeamID. Have to select random players from both sides and also use teamId automatically instead of manually enter ids

```
WITH RandomPlayers AS (
    SELECT
        tp.PlayerId,
        tp.TeamId,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tp.TeamId ORDER BY NEWID()) AS RowNum
    FROM
        TeamPlayerMapping tp
    WHERE
        tp.TeamId IN (15, 19)
)
INSERT INTO Match (Player_1_id, Player_2_id)
SELECT
    Team1.PlayerId AS Player1Id,
    Team2.PlayerId AS Player2Id
FROM
    (SELECT PlayerId, RowNum FROM RandomPlayers WHERE TeamId = 15 ) AS Team1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 PlayerId
    FROM RandomPlayers Team2
    WHERE Team2.TeamId = 19 AND Team2.RowNum = Team1.RowNum
    ORDER BY NEWID()
) AS Team2
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Match m
        WHERE (m.Player_2_id = Team2.PlayerId)
           OR (m.Player_1_id  = Team1.PlayerId)
);
```

tables used for this purpose

```
MapId  TeamId PlayerID
254       15    31
255        19   34
256         15  35
257        19   30
258        15   29
259        19   33
260        15   32
261        19   36
```

```
MatchID Player_1_id  Player_2_id
258             35           36
259             29           34
260              31          36 
261             32           36
```

This code works well for team1 but not for team 2  also I want to get teamId automatically
images of tables I am using are uploaded
Advanced thanks to all [sql output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Goo1m.png)

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it.

Comment: ... Preferably as DDL + DML statements.. For more information., read [sql-server tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info)

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: [edit] all clarifications into your question.

Comment: code updated with tables and attributes,

Comment: Please correct the formatting at the end of your question.... (where your code stops, and your data begins. )

Comment: What is the use of your `WHERE NOT EXIST...` when PlayerId's are unique (according to your sample data) ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.PlayerId, t2.PlayerId
FROM (SELECT PlayerId, row_number() over (order by newid()) as R
      FROM TeamPlayerMapping
      WHERE TeamId=15) t1
INNER JOIN (
     SELECT PlayerId, row_number() over (order by newid()) as R
     FROM TeamPlayerMapping
     WHERE TeamId = 19
) t2 ON t1.R = t2.R
```

- Assign each Player with a unique rownumber
- `INNER JOIN` the teams.

My assumption is that both teams have the same number of players, and that the playerId's are unique.

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/nA8xW7vN)

P.S. Your solution will get duplicate Players from Team2 because the CROSS APPLY is done for every row in Team1. Doing it once, will prevent duplicates.

Comment: Please read: [What are some good ways to improve English grammar and writing abilities for a non-native speaker?](https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-word-dear-actually-mean-when-someone-calls-you-that), and I am In for the answer: **I hate being called dear by men I don’t really know. I find it condescending.**